# two queries returning different result counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two queries I've tested:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [PreferredName], [DOB], [Sex], LastActivityDate,LoweredEmail, EmailConfirmed FROM [Patients] p 
join AspNetUsers u on p.Id=u.PatientId 
join AspNetUserRoles r on u.Id=r.UserId
WHERE (p.[ClinicId] = 1) and RoleId='16874754-779a-fbae-8caf-bbbb2344b7a6'
```

it returns 1301 results

but this query

```
SELECT AspNetUsers.id FROM dbo.AspNetUsers 
INNER JOIN dbo.AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id=AspNetUserRoles.UserId 
WHERE AspNetUsers.ClinicId = 1 and AspNetUserRoles.RoleID='16874754-779a-fbae-8caf-bbbb2344b7a6'
```

this one returns 1303

I've tried this query to check the ones missing and it's getting zero results

```
    SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [PreferredName], [DOB], [Sex], LastActivityDate,LoweredEmail, EmailConfirmed FROM [Patients] p 
    join AspNetUsers u on p.Id=u.PatientId 
    join AspNetUserRoles r on u.Id=r.UserId
    WHERE (p.[ClinicId] = 1) and RoleId='16874754-779a-fbae-8caf-bbbb2344b7a6'
    and u.PatientId not in
    (
    SELECT AspNetUsers.PatientId FROM dbo.AspNetUsers INNER JOIN 
    dbo.AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id=AspNetUserRoles.UserId WHERE
    AspNetUsers.ClinicId = 1 and 
    AspNetUserRoles.RoleID='16874754-779a-fbae-8caf-bbbb2344b7a6'
    )
```

How do I find out which is correct, and why am I getting a difference?

Comment: Can we assume that for each query, you are guaranteed to get one and only one PatientID per row?

Comment: @Xedni yeah the id is a unique identifier column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second query is returning 1303 records:

```
SELECT AspNetUsers.id
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers INNER JOIN
     dbo.AspNetUserRoles
     ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId 
WHERE AspNetUsers.ClinicId = 1 and
      AspNetUserRoles.RoleID='16874754-779a-fbae-8caf-bbbb2344b7a6'
```

The first query is returning 1301 records:

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [PreferredName], [DOB], [Sex],   
       LastActivityDate, LoweredEmail, EmailConfirmed
FROM [Patients] p join
     AspNetUsers u
     on p.Id = u.PatientId join
     AspNetUserRoles r
     on u.Id = r.UserId
WHERE (p.[ClinicId] = 1) and RoleId='16874754-779a-fbae-8caf-bbbb2344b7a6'
```

The difference between these two is the join on `Patients`.  This is an `inner join`, so it may be filtering results.  Note that duplicates could also cause problems.

You can determine the rows that are missing (because some are missing) with:

```
select *
from AspNetUsers nu
where not exists (select 1 from patents p where p.id = nu.PatientId);
```

Comment: well I ran `select *
from AspNetUsers nu
where not exists (select * from Patients p where p.id = nu.PatientId);` and found only 1 result so far, but the clinicId is null so that shouldn't be one of the two problem users.

Comment: @prospector . . . I would guess that that non-patient has two roles.

Comment: I wish you were right, but it's returning only 1 role.

Comment: Another possibility is that `AspNetUsers.PatientId` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried    SELECT DISTINCT?
Also try your checking query the other way (subquery to main query, main query to subquery)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicates in your second query. The first uses `clinicid` from `patient` whereas the second uses it from `aspusers` table. The suspect is `clinicid` of `aspusers` table. Check its same as in `patient`. To find difference minus `aspusers` from `patient`